# Android app to record loud live music with a minimum of audio artifacts

Tags: android, audio, music, audio-recording, voice-recording

I am seeking recommendations for Android apps to record loud live music.

The Android device will be located within 2.5 meters (~8 feet) of many of the non-amplified instruments.  Those non-amplified instruments are drums, and are impressively loud.

Using several different Android audio recording apps, I have already made some recordings.  In each of the recordings, there is an audible clicking sound coinciding with many of the times the drums reach their loudest peak amplitude.

I even tried recording using [AudioLab](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hitrolab.audioeditor) with the microphone gain set to -6dB and output set to be a non-compressed WAV file.  Unfortunately, that did not generate any better results.

Please recommend any Android apps that might be able to successfully record loud music with a minimum of audio artifacts.

Gratis and open-source are always a plus, but any price is acceptable, and the app does not have to be open-source.